# Formidable Forms Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code:

```
add_filter('frm_get_default_value', 'form_fullname_value', 10, 2);

function form_fullname_value($name_value, $field){
 //set array with all form fullname id's
$name_array = array(94, 83, 101, 185, 165, 114, 151);

 //Set value for each fullname field
  if(in_array($field->id, $name_array)){
  //check if GET is set
    if(isset( $_GET[ 'fullname' ] ))
      {
       $name_value = sanitize_text_field( $_GET[ 'fullname' ] );
       //write cookie
       setcookie("VNX[fullname]", $name_value);
      }
  else{ //see is cookie is set    
       if(isset($_COOKIE['VNX']['fullname']))
         { 
          $name_value = $_COOKIE['VNX']['fullname']; 
         }
      }  
  }
  return $name_value;
}
```

This pre fills the form fields in formidable form. It works ok as the forms are indeed prefilled. BUT One of the options is to click a check box which reveals the form fields which are to be displayed (set as display none) relative to that option.
When I use the above function the fields are not displayed (remain hidden).
If I use the wordpress admin area to give the fields a value they work correctly.
I have tried just passing a string to form via this function but with the same result.
Has anyone come across this before and if so how did you make it work.
Thanks in advance.
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone looking for this as a fix I used frm_setup_new_fields_vars function instead:

```
add_filter('frm_setup_new_fields_vars', 'form_fullname_value', 10, 2);

function form_fullname_value($name_value, $field){
 //set array with all form fullname id's
$name_array = array(94, 83, 101, 185, 165, 114, 151);

//Set value for each fullname field
if(in_array($field->id, $name_array)){
//check if GET is set
if(isset( $_GET[ 'fullname' ] ))
  {
   $name_value['value'] = sanitize_text_field( $_GET[ 'fullname' ] );
   //write cookie
   setcookie("VNX[fullname]", $name_value['value']);
  }
else{ //see is cookie is set    
   if(isset($_COOKIE['VNX']['fullname']))
     { 
      $name_value['value'] = $_COOKIE['VNX']['fullname']; 
     }
  }  
}
return $name_value;
}
```